# Best/easiest way to save data+relational data in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api2

Consider this simple one to many relationship in Entity Framework. One organisation holds many products.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(300)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public float Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Organisation Organisation { get; set; }

    public Product()
    {
        CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
    }
}

public class Organisation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [StringLength(400)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

If I have a (post) api call, accepting raw data in the body (json formatted text), which allows the user to create an organisation and as many products as they want, in the same call. How do I correctly save these data into the database using Entity Framework?

As far as I know I am using lazy loading (due to virtual keywords when setting relations in the models), so shouldn't it handle relations automatically? If I save the data like in the controller action below (the controller action for the post call). Will it work? And if it doesn't, what is the appropriate/best practice method for saving a model that contains a list of another model using Entity Framework.

```
public IHttpActionResult CreateOrganisation(Organisation org)
{           
    db.Organisations.Add(org);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Ok(org);
}
```

Really can't seem to find this in the docs?

Comment: _Will it work?_ - did you tried it?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if it works or not. I just put it there to show you what I meant. I am looking for a concrete example on the "best practice" way of doing this.

Comment: If it works - it is a best practice. If later you got issues(performance, scalability, readability ...) - you will refactor it to remove issues and that code will be best practice for your application. Best practices is all about concrete context. In your example you provided it should work and comprehensible enough.

Comment: I understand your viewpoint, but that's not really true. Just because you don't know a better/more efficient way of doing something, doesn't mean that it doesn't exist. Using your logic, every solution is the best until you learn of a new one. If that's true, consider this post my way of learning a better one.

Comment: As I said programming is all about context. In context of your question - adding new organisation is good enough. Give us some specific problem and possbly there will be better approach,

Answer (score 0):

Well, i didn´t have time to try it, but looking at your code i see that there are some suggestions that i may point to you if you are looking for the best practices even if these don´t anwser your question:

1. Make your Web API Controller using the Async Task pattern to avoid dead locks:

   ```
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> CreateOrganisation(Organisation org)
   ```
2. Make the caller method, the business logic of your ef, as the same pattern above. In this case use the SaveChangesAsync() method.  Don´t forget to use also the keyword await when calling any method as the example above within your controller.
3. Make the use of the separation of concerns. Apply the BL out of your Controller class.
4. Apply the SOLID principle. Dependency of inversion, letter D,  for example using the Microsfot Unity IOC container, make the classes loosely coupled using abstract classes, interfaces, so after that apply the dependency of injection.
5. Try to use a View Model to valide the model instead of the domain class generated by the datafirst model or the code first model by the EF.
6. Last but not least, strongly typed!!!!

I hope these suggestions would help you.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of most of this though, I just wanted to make a simple example to make a point. Was hoping to get some code examples of the best way to save relation data. These classes are not actually a part of my work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for "best practices", I'll tell you about a technique I had to work with back when EF's handling of object graphs was a little, shall we say "iffy"?

First, each physically stored entity has a corresponding DTO object.  Part of the ViewModel (MVVM-speak) was the necessary DTO object(s) for that View.  There were additional fields added to communicate State (what the UI did) for each entity.  It looked something like this:

```
public class ProductDTO {
    // Same fields, mostly
    public string Action { get; set; }    // A, C, D
}

public class OrganizationDTO {
    // Same fields except children
    public ICollection<ProductDTO> Products { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

Based on non-blank Action in the top level DTO, POST, PUT or DELETE (A,C,D). UI sets the states of each entity. A modification to children counts as a "change" to the parent.

Then in my CRUD methods on the backend ... Admittedly, this is the sledgehammer approach.

```
public class OrganizationRepository : whatever interfaces {
    public void Add (OrganizationDTO newOrg) {
        if (newOrg.Action != "A")    // Why are you here?
           throw an exception (bad request)

        context.Organizations.Add(Map DTO to entity here);
        foreach (var item in newOrg.Products) {
            switch (item.Action)
            case "A":
                ProductRepository.Add(item,newOrg.Id);
                break;
            case "C":
                ProductRepository.Update(item,newOrg.Id);
                break;
            case "D":
                ProductRepository.Delete(item);
                break;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Update (OrganizationDTO oldOrg) {
        if (newOrg.Action != "C")    // Why are you here?
           throw an exception (bad request)

        context.Organizations.Attach(Map DTO to entity here);
        foreach (var item in newOrg.Products) {
            switch (item.Action)
            case "A":
                ProductRepository.Add(item,newOrg.Id);
                break;
            case "C":
                ProductRepository.Update(item,newOrg.Id);
                break;
            case "D":
                ProductRepository.Delete(item);
                break;
        }
        context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This is not working/tested code.  Just rough off-the-cuff.  Have to handle FKs on adds.  Add your mapping technique.  Handle collisions, Try/Catch, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I think your code is not well self-explaining.
If I'm a developer that looks at the method you posted here, I would simply not understand that i have the possibility to send nested-data.

I would make an iteration over the Products collection of the object "org" and add them to their EF collection, then late add the Organisation to its own.

Then, obviously, SaveChanges().

This would clearly distinguish this method that accept nested object, from another ipothetical that doesn't and simply saves my new empty Organisation.

Comment: That might be necessary if you aren't using lazy loading, which I am.

Comment: Lazy loading has to do with reading data, from your question I understand you have doubts about saving data.